# jackson parser backslash double quote not work

Tags: json, jackson, backslash

I met a problem when I try to convert json to map.

I use jakson, and here is my mapper():

```
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setTimeZone(TimeFormat.getDefaultTimeZone());
        mapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature.REQUIRE_SETTERS_FOR_GETTERS, false);
        mapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, true);
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        format.setTimeZone(TimeFormat.getDefaultTimeZone());
        mapper.setDateFormat(format);
```

Here is the 'bad' json:

```
{..."id":660273193,"orderId":220575205,"orderItemAmount":5.6,"orderItemNum":2,"orderItemPrice":2.8,"productCName":"16\\" Shoes","productId":23373137,...
```

Error Info is:**Unexpected character ('S' (code 22609 / 0x5851)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries**
The user set 16" 10 as the productName, but failed converting it from json to map.
I tried Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER but not work.
Are there any configurations that I haven't found for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you should use one backslash to escape a quote if you are reading from an external source, or three backslashes if you are reading a JSON string from a Java constant. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonBackslash {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       // mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, true);
        String json = "{\"productCName\":\"16\\\" Shoes\"}";
        System.out.println(json);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"productCName":"16\" Shoes"}
{productCName=16" Shoes}
```

Comment: I tested your code, it's totally ok, but the strange thing is that I checked the source: 16\" Shoes,failed... I can find this subString using r.indexOf("\\\" Shoes");